# C automatically assign port

Tags: c, networking

I just wanted to know how to use C to automatically assign a free port (and see what was used) if a specific port number is not provided.

For example, i'm using this:

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address->sin_family = AF_INET;
address->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address->sin_port = htons( port );
```

But how can I replace the sin_port assignment and let C automatically assign for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt has already answered the "how to assign a free port" part (use sin_port = 0).

To answer the second part, i.e. "how to see what was used", use [getsockname()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738543(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this one answered the question fully.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a value of `0`.

```
address->sin_port = 0
```

Alternatively, you can completely skip the binding step if you don't care which interface you use, either.

Comment: Thanks for this - I couldn't seem to find anywhere stating that a value of 0 would do this.